# Javascript - Create array with inputs values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a foreach php like this:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
   <h2>{{$post->title}}</h2>
   <img src="{{$post->image}}" width="150" height="150">
   <p>{{$post->country}}</p>
   <p>{{$post->zone}}</p>
   <p>{{$post->user->name}}</p>
   <input type="hidden" class="postId" value="{{$post->id}}" name="postId">
   <p class="expiredate">{{$post->expire_date}}</p>
   <p class="current">{{$current}}</p>
@endforeach
```

I would like do an array javascript with values of inputs hiddens, like this:

```
var inputsArray= [value first input, value second input, value....]
```

i'm tryng like this:

```
var d = document;    
var inputsArray = d.querySelectorAll('.postId');
```

but it doen't work, my console give me:

```
console.log(inputArray.value) = undefined
```

Comment: Maybe because your spelling of `inputArray` is inconsistent?

Comment: also, try just `console.log(inputArray)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your variable to a true array, since `querySelectorAll` returns a node list, not an array. Then iterate over that array, as the array itself has no `value` property:

```
var d = document;    
var inputsArray = Array.from(d.querySelectorAll('.postId'));

inputsArray.forEach(function (input) {
    console.log(input.value);
});
```

Comment: I have just come to the awareness of the fact that `Array.from(arrayLikeThingy)` is much slower than `[...arrayLikeThingy]`

Comment: why slower? @Redu

Comment: This will depend on the JavaScript engine. Anyway, there is no practical difference in this situation at hand. You 'd need to have a node list with tens of thousands of elements before you could start noticing a difference.

Comment: @Diego Cespedes To be honest I can not tell exactly why but this morning i was trying some bench-marking and when i converted the `[...x]` into `Array.from(x)` on a code which was doing tons of it repeatedly, the resolution of the code prolonged more than double.

Comment: @trincot Agreed.. It was just my five cents for future reference.